# Delete any cells with values greater than specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro for the following:

For each row, if there are cell values in range `C3:ACP3` that are `>=` value of `ACU3`, I want to replace that cell value with blank.  I want to do this for every row, and each time the macro should reference the value in the `ACU` column for that row.

Comment: What `vba` have you already written?

Comment: You could use traditional conditional formatting to hide the content of the cell by making the font colour the same as the background colour?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub makeBlank()

Dim r As Range
Set r = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:ACP3")

Dim v As Double
v = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ACU3").Value

Dim c
For Each c In r
    If c.Value >= v Then
        c.Value = ""
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

I suspect this will be quicker using arrays:

```
Sub makeBlank2()

Dim v
v = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ACU3").Value

Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Sheet1.Range("C3:ACP3")

Dim R, C As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        If Arr(R, C) > v Then
            Arr(R, C) = ""
        End If
    Next C
Next R

Sheet1.Range("C3:ACP3") = Arr

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3561283 - did it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FindDelete()

Dim ACU_Val As Double
Dim cl As Range
Dim rw As Long

    For rw = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Range("ACU" & rw).Value = "" Then Exit For

        ACU_Val = Range("ACU" & rw).Value

        For Each cl In Range("C" & rw & ":ACP" & rw)
            If cl.Value >= ACU_Val Then cl.Value = ""
        Next cl
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: why loop through `Rows.Count` ?

Comment: " I want to do this for every row, and each time the macro should reference the value in the ACU column for that row."
- user3561283

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
Dim myCell As Range
numberOfRows = 1000

For i = 0 To numberOfRows 
    Dim myRow As Range

    Set myRow = [C3:ACP3].Offset(i, 0)
    bound = Intersect([acu3].EntireColumn, myRow.EntireRow) 

    For Each myCell In myRow
        If myCell >= bound Then myCell = ""
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I shied away from the concise square brackets notation....I've actually ended up now going for the polar opposite just to guarantee that my Excel server knows execatly which bit of memory I'm referencing: so rather than `[A1]` I'd have something like `Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`

Comment: You are right but my code is entended to be pasted in the corresponding worksheed code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over your desired range of cells and for each cell which contents are above the threshold value in the `ACU` column of the same row just clear its contents.

```
For Each c In Range("C3:ACP3")
  If c.Value >= Cells(c.Row, "ACU") Then
    c.clearContents
  End If
Next c
```

Comment: Isn't storing the value of `Cells(c.Row, "ACU")` before the loop better practice?